# Как создать таблицу основаную на пользовательском типе данных?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть следующий фрагмент кода:

```
Create Type person;
Create Type child AS Table Of Ref person;
Create Type person AS Object(
    name varchar(10),
    father ref person,
    children child);
```

В чем разница между первым и вторым запросом на создание типа `person`?
А также, как можно создать таблицу `Employee` на основе типа `person` и вставить в нее данные?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Create a table based on a type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65643009) от участника [@Sandra Guilep Zouaoui Zandeh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9517769/sandra-guilep-zouaoui-zandeh)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65643009

Answer (score 2):

> В чем разница между первым и вторым запросом на создание типа `person`?

```sql
Create Type person
/
Create Type child AS Table Of Ref person
/
```

Это предварительная декларация типа. На данный момент, тип не является полным, но он указывает БД, что он существует и может быть использован в других DDL выражениях. Предварительная декларация необходима для того, чтобы можно было создать тип `child`, так как оно ссылается на тип `person`.

```sql
Create Type person AS Object (
    name     varchar(10),
    father   ref person,
    children child)
/
```

Вторая декларация `person` является полной декларацией типа. Он не может быть реализован до тех пор, пока не будет реализован тип `child`, который, в свою очередь, не может быть реализован до тех пор, пока БД не будет знать, что существует тип `person`, что создаст круговую цепочку зависимостей. Предварительное декларирование типа разрывает её.

> как можно создать таблицу Employee на основе типа `person`?

Простейшее решение:

```sql
create table Employee of Person
    nested table children store as employee_children;
```

Но вероятно, необходимо указать первичный ключ, а также то, что областью видимости для столбцов `REF` является таблица `Employee`. Тогда можно это сделать так:

```sql
Create Type person
/
Create Type child AS Table Of Ref person
/
Create type person as object (
    id       number,
    name     varchar(10),
    father   ref person,
    children child)
/
Create table Employee of Person (
    father scope is Employee,
    constraint Employee_PK primary key (id)
) nested table children store as employee_children
/
alter table employee_children add scope for (column_value) is Employee;
```

И вставить в нее данные с `INSERT`:

```sql
insert into Employee values (1, 'Chef', null, child());

insert into Employee values (2, 'Clerk 1', ( 
    select ref(e) from Employee e where id = 1), child());

insert into Employee values (3, 'Clerk 2', ( 
    select ref(e) from Employee e where id = 1), child());

insert into table (select children from Employee where id = 1)
    (select ref(e) from Employee e where id in (2,3));
```

Получим результат:

```sql
select 
    e.id, e.name, c.column_value.id child_id, c.column_value.name child_name
from employee e outer apply table (e.children) c
/

        ID NAME         CHILD_ID CHILD_NAME
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Chef                2 Clerk 1   
         1 Chef                3 Clerk 2   
         2 Clerk 1                         
         3 Clerk 2
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65643747) от участника [@MT0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1509264/mt0)</sub>